# Global sections of $LX/SO(1,3) \to X$ are pseudo-Riemannian metrics... how, why?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, metric-spaces

On page 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0208054.pdf, the author claims:

> When the gauge theory was formulated in terms of bundles, the very
> definition of the pseudo-Riemannian metric on a manifold X as a global
> section of the quotient bundle $$\Sigma_{PR} = {\rm LX} / {\rm SO}(1, 3) \to {\rm X}$$

I believe that that LX is ${\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.

Am I correct to understand that the global sections ${\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})/{\rm SO}(1, 3)$ are the pseudo-Riemmanian metrics?

---

I am trying to visualize this claim in 2D

Say I have a ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix:

$$
\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}, \det\mathbf{M} >0
$$

and a matrix of ${\rm SO}(1,1)$

$$
\mathbf{S}=\begin{bmatrix}  \cosh \theta & \sinh \theta \\ \sinh \theta & \cosh \theta \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, how do I divide $\mathbf{M}$ with $\mathbf{S}$ such that I get a metric? Do I multiply $\mathbf{M}$ with $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ (the matrix inverse of $\mathbf{S}$)?

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Comment: Do you know what associated bundles are? Your interpretation is not quite right.

Comment: "I believe that that $LX$ is $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$" No, the article states that $LX$ is the frame bundle of the tangent space. This means the following: Take any point $x$ on your space $X$ ($X$ is a 4D [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)). Then consider the space of tangent vectors at $x$, this is $T_xX$. The space $T_xX$ is a vector space, and you can have "frames"/bases of this vector space. Now nicely collect all these possible bases into one big space $L_xX$, and then for each $x\in X$ collect these $L_xX$ into a nice space $LX$. This is $LX$, it is not $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @student91 crystal clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an orientable four manifold. So the tangent frame bundle is given by
$$
LX \to X,
$$
which is a principal $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$-bundle. By choosing an orientation on $X$, you can reduce the structure group to $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.
The (quotient) bundle
$$
LX /SO(1,3) \to X
$$
is the bundle containing the oriented tangent frames up to $SO(1,3)$-equivalence.

Now, the paper you linked explains on how global sections of that bundle give rise to pseudo-Riemannian metrics on $X$.

Comment: Wouldn't those metrics already be present to define SO(1,3)?

Comment: No, $SO(1,3)$ is just the isometry group of $3+1$ dimensional Minkowski spacetime and have nothing to do with the manifold a priori.

Comment: So SO(1,3) contains the Lorentz metric, but not the pseudo-Riemannian ones over the whole manifold?

Comment: In local trivialization, they are the same. The issue comes from finding a globally defined pseudo-Riemannian metric, which probably has to satisfy additional properties.